# Tomcat webapp failing to start when Tomcat started as a service

Tags: linux, tomcat, java, service

I have a webapp that is failing to start in Tomcat on a Linux install. The app works on a different Tomcat installs on different machines and on the same machine when using a standalone Tomcat.

The problem seems to be due to the way in which Tomcat is starting.

- Usining `service tomcat8 start` fails when Tomcat is installed through the package manager;
- Using `/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start` fails when Tomcat is installed through the package manager;
- Using a standalone tomcat and starting with `service tomcat8 start` (having modified `/etc/init.d/tomcat8`) fails;
- Using a standalone tomcat and starting using `./startup.sh` works.

I am using Debian 8, Tomcat 8.0.11 (but have tried 8.0.9 and 8.0.11) and various versions of Java. The app is failing due to a java transaction manager called *Atomikos*. The error is:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class uk.co.prodia.talkingcouch.ApplicationContextListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContext-db-sessionfactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'atomikosTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'atomikosTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContext-db-sessionfactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.transaction.SystemException: Transaction service not running
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually management script are reading additional properties from the script itself, from files in /etc/tomcat8 and even from /etc/default/tomcat(8)

Ensure that the command with arguments issued from the startup.sh and from the management scripts result in the same call.

You can try to get the parameters
    ps -fp 
    cat /proc//cmdline

Answer (score 0):

TheCodeKiller got me to thinking along the right way. It was ultimately a permission issue and my own instance was only working at it was running as `root`. This was obvious by comparing the `ps` output of each running process.

Atomikos was writing its log file out to `$CATALINA_BASE` which was at `/var/lib/tomcat8` which is only root writable.

It turns out that Atomikos had changed the way in handles logging and so that I had to:

- Deleted the property `com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir`;
- Deleted the property `com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir`.

and then add the following to `log4j.xml`:

```
<appender name="tc-core-atomikos" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/stroage/www/tc/data/atomikos/tmout"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="tc-core-atomikos => [log level: %-5p] [thread: %t] [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}]%n    %c %M%n        %m%n%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.atomikos">
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="tc-core-atomikos"/>
</logger>
```